# How do I configure external-dns to create A Record, not CNAME

Tags: kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-helm, linode

I am following Linode's tutorials on using helm to deploy to Linode Kubernetes Engine (LKE) and I have reached [the section on configuring external DNS](https://youtu.be/wLHegOz_aR4?t=661) which uses [bitnami's external-dns package](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/external-dns) to configure a domain on Linode's DNS servers.

When I try to annotate my service, using exactly the same command as in the video, it results in a CNAME alias and no A/TXT Records.

The logs from the external-dns show

> time="2022-01-01T14:45:10Z" level=info msg="Creating record." action=Create record=juicy type=CNAME zoneID=1770931 zoneName=mydomain.com
>
> time="2022-01-01T14:45:11Z" level=info msg="Creating record." action=Create > record=juicy type=TXT zoneID=1770931 zoneName=mydomain.com
>
> time="2022-01-01T14:45:11Z" level=error msg="Failed to Create record: [400] [name] Record conflict - CNAMES must be unique" action=Create record=juicy type=TXT zoneID=1770931 zoneName=mydomain.com

These logs imply that external-dns is first creating a CNAME record (which isn't required/wanted at all) and then attempting to create a TXT record which uses the same hostname as the newly-created CNAME, which obviously isn't allowed. And it is clearly not attempting to create the A Record at all.

I would really appreciate any info about why this might be happening and what I can do to correct it. For clarity, the desired result is one A Record and one TXT Record, both with the hostname 'juicy'

Comment: I have found in the [FAQs for external-dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/faq.md#can-i-force-externaldns-to-create-cname-records-for-elbalb) that it will create an ALIAS if the target looks like an Elastic Load Balancer. I don't know if this is relevant to my issue, however the solution provided in the FAQs is specific to AWS. It also doesn't explain why Linode's video tutorials don't have this issue when using the exact same commands

Comment: Can you paste the annotate command that you used to annotate the {juicy?} service for externa-dns to process? Will be better if you paste the (juicy?) service spec altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears this is due to *external-dns* applying some logic which [detects if the target is an Elastic Load Balancer](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/faq.md#can-i-force-externaldns-to-create-cname-records-for-elbalb).

After creating the CNAME alias, *external-dns* is then trying to create a TXT Record with the same hostname, which is failing because this is not allowed. To get around this, *external-dns* provides a [`--txt-prefix` flag](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/faq.md#im-using-an-elb-with-txt-registry-but-the-cname-record-clashes-with-the-txt-record-how-to-avoid-this) which allows you to prefix the TXT hostname with a string, thus making it different from the newly-created CNAME record.

Arguably, *external-dns* does not need to switch from A Record to CNAME in this instance because Linode's Load Balancers have IP addresses, not domain names. An issue has been raised [on GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/issues/2499).

If you're following Linode's excellent tutorial and/or you're installing *external-dns* with helm, the `--txt-prefix` flag needs to be set at installation:

```
helm install external-dns bitnami/external-dns \                                                                                                                               
  --namespace external-dns --create-namespace \
  --set provider=linode \
  --set linode.apiToken=$LINODE_API_TOKEN \
--set txtPrefix=your-prefix-string
```

(*namespace* and other values are included to match the Linode tutorials)
The rest of the tutorial can then be followed as is.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the A record in route-53 i am not sure you are on which cloud or so.

in document search for `aws.preferCNAME` you can see in deployment that's where changes need to be configured.

External DNS will create the A record also please check your deployment configuration.

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: external-dns
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: external-dns
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: external-dns
        image: registry.opensource.zalan.do/teapot/external-dns:v0.3.0-beta.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        args:
        - --domain-filter=$(DOMAIN_FILTER)
        - --source=service
        - --source=ingress
        - --provider=aws
        env:
        - name: DOMAIN_FILTER
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: external-dns
              key: domain-filter
```

there could be chances, `--aws-prefer-cname` line with **CNAME** config which is making external **DNS** force to create CNAME instead of A record.

Remove **CNAME** config and check by default it will create the **A** record.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The tutorial uses helm charts to deploy external-dns on Linode Kubernetes Engine and configure the Linode DNS servers. It isn't touching AWS at all. I have updated my question to be more explicit about this.